# looping in beautiful soup / no errors

Tags: python, selenium, loops, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have been writing a program that would hypothetically find items on a website as soon as they were loaded onto the website. As of now the script takes as input, two different values (keywords) used to describe an item and a color used to pick the color of the item. The parsing is spot on with items that are already on the website but lets say that I run my program before the website loads the items, instead of having to re run the entire script i'd like for it to just refresh the page and re-parse the data until it found it. I also included no errors in my question because from my example run of the script I entered Keywords and Color not pertaining to item on the website and instead of getting an error, I just got " Process finished with exit code 0". Thank you in advance to any who take the time to help !

Here is my code:
[image]

Comment: Why can't you just simply use selenium for your initial loading too, rather using requests and then BS. WIth selenium you can launch the browser and then get all the `li>a` items and do the same stuff what you are trying in the loop.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: I am new to scraping thus I hadn't know that selenium could scrape as well but now I know, Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As another user suggested, you're probably better off using Selenium for the entire process rather than using it for only parts of your code and swapping between BSoup and Selenium.

As for reloading the page if certain items are not present, if you already know which items are supposed to be on the page then you can simply search for each item by id with selenium and if you can't find one or more then refresh the page with the following line of code:

```
driver.refresh()
```